# How to write an @Path regular expression to capture these parts of the path with whitespace in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs, resteasy

Given a URI like:

```
/2013/03%20-%20March/15%20-%20Friday/1AC37325007
```

I have tried the following and I can't seem to get a match;

```
"/{year:\\d{4}}/{month:\\d{2}}\\s-\\s\\w+/{day:\\d{2}}\\s-\\s\\w+/{id:\\w{11}}"
```

It is the `month` and `day` expressions that are not matching, because when I change them to capture everything between the `/` it matches `{month}/{day}/`, etc. But I need to extract only the numbers portion so that isn't an elegant solution.

I think it is the whitespace that is tripping me up, I can't get it to match on `%20` and I can't get it to match on `\s` either.

Comment: you want to match the uri before or after it was encoded?

Comment: I don't have any control over this JAX-RS ( RestEasy/Jersey ) is doing the matching magically for me. I can get other things to match that don't have any whitespace just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is what I got working through trial and error:

```
@Path("/{year:\\d{4}}/{month:\\d{2}}{noop0:%20-%20\\w+}/{day:\\d{2}}{noop1:%20-%20\\w+}/{id:\\w{11}}")
```

Notice that *all* the regular expression expressions have to be enclosed in `{ }` even if you aren't going to use the results of the grouping.

I named mine `noop0` and `noop1` to mark them as `no operation` operations.

Also it appears that the regular expression matching is done *pre-decoding* and the results of the match are then URL decoded.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax like `{year:\\d{4}}` is an illegal repetition:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("{date:\\d}");
```

gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{date:\d}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2775)
```

Try using `\\d{4}` instead.

Also `\\s-\\s` won't match `%20-%20` unless you perform URL decoding on the string beforehand

You can enclose part of the expression with brackets and capture only that portion later

Comment: the year part matches and captures just fine as stated in the original question

Comment: I added supporting evidence of my observation above that that syntax throws exception in Java

Comment: this isn't the case, this is being pre-processed by JAX-RS, it is completely valid syntax, it is the whitespace I am having a problem with.